# How to implement drill-down mechanism on geographical data in Deneb for PowerBI using Vega-lite

Tags: powerbi, vega-lite, vega, deneb

I'm trying to create a map in Deneb using vega-lite which replicates the drill-down mechanism, meaning that starting from the overview of the Lombardy region in Italy (picture below) divided by its provinces, I can click on one of the province and drill-down to the cities level, as shown below.

I managed to do so by using multiple layers, as shown in the images below: when the user click on one of the Province, the map focus on that province and shows the cities level.

[Province level of the Lombardy region (Italy)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NvvKC.png)

[Cities level of one of the province when selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yjC6V.png)

However, there is a problem I cannot solve: when the user is at the cities level, he can further select one city to filter the other visuals in the PowerBI report with that city. The problem is: when the user selects one of the city, the map will further zoom on that city, as shown below, and this is not the behavior I want. I would prefer that when a city is selected, the other cities greys out and only the selected territory remains colored.

[the problem of the "zoom" on the city when it is selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kTABT.png)

[Expected behavior: when the user selects one city inside the territory of the selected Province, the other cities grey out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D6n1n.png)

Here is my code: [text](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/MikeADL/Varie/main/Code%20for%20Deneb%20visual)

Thank you in advance for the help

Comment: the vega lite maps look nice. Any reason you didn't go with the power bi map visuals or Azure Map? I believe the zooming behavior you're looking for is included with Azure map.

Comment: @zach yes you're right, that functionality is available in the azure map visual, but unfortunately this visual is still not working in report that are embedded in a website using the "Publish to web" method.